# Android tabs hosting an intent as content

Tags: android, panoramas, 360-degrees

Hello in my android project I have an activity which is responsible for showing multimedia to the user. I have a Tabhost which hosts 3 tabs, The first is a viewpager with ImageViews the second is a listView and in the third I'm displaying a 360 photo using a PanoramaGL library. My problem is that in the third tab I set as content an intent so that a specific class from the panoramaGL library would be created in order to display the photo.

**MY PROBLEM:** since I set in the tab spec an intent as content it uses too much memory. But I need to create in that tab this activity. what can I do?